# What do you call the act of signing a document in the presence of an notary?

Tags: correspondence

I'm asking person A (signer of document) to sign a document in the presence of a notary (N).

How do I ask person A to do this?

"Dear A,

Please notarize the document?
"

This makes it sound like I'm asking A to act as the notary, when really N is the notary.

I usually go with something like,

"Dear A,

Please sign X taking care to have it notarized.
"

Comment: You already have a verb in mind: "notarize". Try to look it up in a dictionary and see if the dictionary answers your question.

Comment: Do you mean you want someone to _swear an affidavit_ ?

Comment: @RMac Wow, what a helpful suggestion.  If I didn't know better, I'd think you didn't read my question carefully and just decided to plop out that self-satisfied rubbish of a comment instead.

Comment: A notary notarizes things, so you can't notarize the document. (It turns out even if you're  a notary,  you can't notarize for yourself.) So you should always ask for someone to have  or get a document notarized.

Answer (score 2):

R Mac suggests in a comment the verb ***to notarize***.

That verb describes what a notary does — whatever he does in your jurisdiction. It’s not what the signatory (or signatories) of a notarized document does (or do).

The signatories *have* their documents (or their consent to agreements) *notarized*. So the request formulation you are looking for, could be:

> Please have your consent (form/document/…) notarized.

---

Another verb is ***to officialize something***.

The meaning is: perform whatever procedure is required to make *something* official. This procedure can involve a notary — but not necessarily. That verb itself does neither indicate what kind of procedure is required, nor whether it involves a notary.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use a passive voice such as "have the document (or the signature) notarized", you could ask the other person to **sign it in the presence of a notary**.

> To get something notarized, you must sign it in the presence of a
>   notary public. The notary must actually watch as you sign the
>   document. They must also validate your identity to be certain you are
>   authorized to sign.
>   https://www.notarize.com/knowledge-center/when-do-i-sign-a-notarized-document

I don't think there is a special word for this, same as there isn't a special word for committing a murder in front of witnesses.

Comment: This is probably fine for most real-life purposes, although if one wanted to be really picky, one could point out that the **presence** of the notary does not logically imply that the notary will, after witnessing the signing, perform the notarizing.

Comment: @jsw29 Why not point out that the notary must also be alive?

Comment: @jsw29 and on planet earth.  Now you are seeing why this is a difficult formulation and I am not thrilled with any of the responses so far.

Comment: @g33kz0r Actually, I don't see why you're having such difficulty with this at all.

Comment: @michael.hor257k I'm not surprised.

Answer (score 0):

I've always heard something akin to "have the document notarized".